# String Comparison inside loop Maple

Tags: string-comparison, maple

I am new to maple. I am having a problem with a small program that will read data from file, perform some calculations and then write back to file. Data being read from the file is required to be compared in order to extract x,y and z data. I can read properly from the file and do the comparison but when I read inside a loop the comparison doesnot work, It seems the compare function is not working at all inside the loop.
Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code?

> with(StringTools):
>
> ```
>      file:=fopen("C:\\Fileread.txt",READ,TEXT);           
>      cryptf:=fopen("C:\\Filewrite.txt",WRITE,TEXT);
>      line :=readline(file);
>      while (line <> 0) do    
>           if    type(Compare(line, "x"),boolean)  then
>             line := readline(file);
>             x[1] = convert(line, decimal, hex);     
>           elif Compare(line, "y") then
>             line := readline(file);
>             Y[1]= convert(line, decimal, hex);
>
>         elif Compare(line, "Z") then  
>             line := readline(file);
>             Z[1] = convert(line, decimal, hex);
>
>         else 
>               d=1;
>         end if;      
>
>      line :=readline(file);
>      writeline(cryptf,X[1]);
>
>    od;
>    close(file);
>    close(cryptf);
> ```

Comment: What is the purpose of **if type(Compare(line, "x"), boolean**? As far as I can see, it will always be boolean (either true or false). Therefore the **line** is discarded and the next **line** read. Then the next line of code, **x[1] = convert(line, ...)**, does nothing because it is not an assignment statement.

Comment: I was just verifying what the statement will return;; that was for debugging purpose mainly. That statement is working fine if i donot use loop (i.e. it is executing line:=readline and so on) but if I use loop then it doesnt comes to next statement. I just cannot understand whats wrong, please if anyone can help that will be much appreciated.

Comment: The lines **x[1]= ...**, **Y[1]= ...**, **Z[1]= ...**, and **d= ...** *do not do anything*; they are not assignment statements. Assignment statements use **:=**, not **=**.